# Upgraded spring-security-oauth to 2.4.1, ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter is now deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

This was my previous class

@EnableResourceServer is deprecated and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer (depreciated) 
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Profile("no-security")
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter (depreciated)  {

  private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

  private final String name;

  @Autowired
  public ResourceServerConfiguration(
    SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport, @Value("${spring.application.name}") String name) {
    this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport);
    resources.accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport);
    resources.resourceId(name);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/**")
      .authenticated()
      .antMatchers("/api/config")
      .permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/**")
      .permitAll();
  }
}
```

How should I adapt this class to work with my upgraded Spring-security-oauth 2.4.1.RELEASE?

Comment: Spring Security OAuth2 project is currently deprecated and Spring Security team has decided to no longer provide support for authorization servers.

Comment: @Amitkumar This question was about the Resource Server, which is fully supported by Spring Security. Regarding the Authorization Server, the Spring Security team has announced a new community-driven project, the [Spring Authorization Server](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legacy Spring Security OAuth project has reached [end-of-life](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/07/end-of-life-for-spring-security-oauth).

OAuth2 Resource Server and Client support is fully integrated into Spring Security.

There is a comprehensive migration guide provided by Spring Security [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide).